# update fields values on change event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this input fields in my html template :

```
<form>
  <input id="id_usd_value">
  <input id="id_rer_value" value="3000">
  <input id="id_euros_value">
</form>
```

And this jquery code that it's supossed to update the usd value if i change pesos value or viceversa depending of the rer value :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        $('#id_usd_value').on('change',
          function(e) {
            $('#id_pesos_value').val(
              Math.round(
                parseFloat($(this).val()) / parseFloat($('#id_rer_value').val())
              ) 
            );
          }
        );

        $('#id_pesos_value').on('change',
          function(e) {
            $('#id_usd_value').val(
              Math.round(
                parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($('#id_rer_value').val())
              ) 
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
    </script>
```

But it's not working, can you please help me ??

Comment: `<input id="id_euros_value">` vs `$('#id_pesos_value')`...? Is this a typo?

Comment: Excuse me, im a noob on jquery, what's a typo ??

Comment: You don't have an input with the ID `id_pesos_value`, but you reference that in your jQuery. Is `<input id="id_euros_value">` supposed to be `<input id="id_pesos_value">`? See @Yoeri's answer

Comment: gee...you're right sorry , but still not working on the template =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery on change event is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617496/jquery-on-change-event-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, see fiddle for working version:
You wrote **id_euros_value** instead of **id_pesos_value**

```
<form>
  <input id="id_usd_value">
  <input id="id_rer_value" value="3000">
  <input id="id_pesos_value">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2x9r9a2v/

Comment: Im so sorry...thanks, i wrote it right now but sill don't work, any idea why ?

Comment: In fiddle works fine, in the code snippet too...but in my template when i change any field value nothing happens....and i already corrected the code id's

Comment: Are you sure you included JQuery?
Do you include this script as a js or is it inline script?
Can you post your includes etc?

Comment: It's inline script, the only call im doing to jquery it's on the script label:
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8" ></script>

Comment: if you open the a network inspector, do you get 200 or 304 on the query file?

Comment: Sorry, got 404, the only warning i get is this on the JS tag inspector :14:39:15.816 Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.1 28

Comment: This in console :
[05/Jan/2016 19:39:05] "GET /cost_control/cost_items/set/jquery-2.0.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 7676

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
  $('#id_usd_value').on('change',
    function(e) {
      $('#id_euros_value').val(
        Math.round(
          parseFloat($(this).val()) / parseFloat($('#id_rer_value').val())
        )
      );
    }
  );

  $('#id_pesos_value').on('change',
    function(e) {
      $('#id_usd_value').val(
        Math.round(
          parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($('#id_rer_value').val())
        )
      );
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="id_usd_value" type="number" placeholder="USD">
  <input id="id_rer_value" type="number" value="3000"  placeholder="USD">
  <input id="id_euros_value" type="number" placeholder="EUR" >
</form>
```

Comment: Sry @Yoeri i was writing the answer while you ended up first eheh

Comment: if you run the code snippet and you put 100000 on the first field and then u click outside (this is when the 'change' event is triggered) you see 33 on the third field and that's what u supposed to do (100000  / 3000 = 33)

Comment: Yes, and if i try it on fiddle as @yoeri suggest it works too, but in my template doesn't