# jQuery on change event is not working

Tags: jquery

I have these input fields in my html template :

```
<form>
  <input id="id_usd_value">
  <input id="id_rer_value" value="3000">
  <input id="id_pesos_value">
</form>
```

And this jQuery code that is supposed to update the usd value if I change pesos value or vice versa depending on the rer value :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        $('#id_usd_value').on('change',
          function(e) {
            $('#id_pesos_value').val(
              Math.round(
                parseFloat($(this).val()) / parseFloat($('#id_rer_value').val())
              ) 
            );
          }
        );

        $('#id_pesos_value').on('change',
          function(e) {
            $('#id_usd_value').val(
              Math.round(
                parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($('#id_rer_value').val())
              ) 
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
    </script>
```

If I test it on https://jsfiddle.net/2x9r9a2v/ or code snippet it works...but in my template nothing happens if I change values.

Comment: any errors in the console? Are you sure the ids are unique? It'll likely be something else within your webpage interferring if it's running fine in jsfiddle . . .

Comment: Nope, not a single one..it's kind of weird i know, but i can't find why it's not working.

Comment: Are you defining your script after html code? If not your DOM is not set by browser and your jQuery isn't able to find those elements

Comment: Yup, code is after. I moved the form everywhere inside the template just to test but still useless

Comment: Chk console is there any error regardig jquery version

Comment: Checked, no problem with the version either

Answer (score 0):

Despise there was no version errors, solved it upgrading to Jquery 2.1.4 and works like a charm, thanks to all.